# React native Android emulator error on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, gradle

I am trying to setup react native to work on an android emulator. I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I am getting this error message when i try to use “react-native run-android”:

```
BUILD FAILED in 1m 21s
28 actionable tasks: 28 executed
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Command failed: ./gradlew installDebug

Error: Command failed: ./gradlew installDebug
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:637:11)
at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:655:13)
at runOnAllDevices (/home/william/react/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:299:19)
at buildAndRun (/home/william/react/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:135:12)
at isPackagerRunning.then.result (/home/william/react/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:65:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
```

Furthermore, it says:

```
A problem was found with the configuration of task ‘:app:installDebug’. File ‘/home/william/Android/platform-tools/adb’ specified for property ‘adbExe’ does not exist.
```

I found an answer that said to replace ‘/’ with ‘’ in my settings.gradle in my react native project. The only thing in that is file however is: rootProject.name = ‘AwesomeProject’ include ‘:app’

I have added:

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

To the end of my bashrc.

Comment: Have you run `source ~/.bashrc` after adding `PATH`, or try to open a new terminal to run react? React cannot find `adb` binary, so either the `PATH` is not set, or `adb` is not installed. Can you verify if `adb` is installed at `Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb`?

Comment: I have updated bashrc yes. There is a file, but not a folder called adb there yes

Answer (score 0):

solution for me was to create `android/local.properties` file and specify SDK path on your disk
`sdk.dir=/username/Android/Sdk`